# ASP.NET MVC issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC app and when I run it, it loads my Index action on my HomeController
by default ok.

But when I put in this URl I get 404  - Not Found error

http://localhost/MyGoogleApp/Home/Index

This is the same for any action I put in in Home Controller.

Something fundamentally wrong, any ideas?

Malcolm

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: IIS7 on Vista, does that help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a configuration problem with URL mapping in IIS itself.
I haven't worked much with IIS7, but I think this is what you should check:

1. Managed pipeline mode should be '[Integrated](http://blogs.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/image_thumb_luSkjA.png)'.
2. web.config should include system.webServer with all standard stuff new MVC project puts there (I can't check what exactly right now).